# Extract month from date

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have one column with dates in format:`dd.mm.yyyy`.

I'm looking for a way to make another column showing the **month** from the first column. This to create a graph showing *Activity per month*. therefore I need the New column to be left empty

Comment: You mean the date is using `point .` instead of `dash - or /` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `=MONTH()` function

> The MONTH function takes just one argument, the date from which you
>   want to extract the month. In the example, the formula is:

More info can be found [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-month-from-date)

Answer (score 0):

You can write,

```
=Month(D3) or 
=Month("01/02/2017") or
```

If you want month name then

```
=Text(A1, "mm")
```

NB: "mmm" will return Month name in 3 characters, "mmmm" will full month name.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean your Date is using `point .` instead of `- or /` you can use:

`=MONTH(DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,".","-")))`

You can drag the formula down
A2 is the initial Date with the format `dd.mm.yyyy`
Substitute will replace `.` with `-` you can change it to `/` if more convenient with your Date settings
Datevalue will convert text to date
Month will give you the Month number

If you need the Name of the Month `January` for example you can use:
`=TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,".","-"),"mmmm")`
you can drag the formula down in your column

If Excel is recognizing the format as date you can just use the normal formula:
`=Text(A2,"mmmm")`
For Name of the month or for number of the month:
`=MONTH(A2)`